# How does Spring PropertyEditor know which Class propert to convert

Tags: spring, propertyeditor

I searched the documentation in Spring and also in Pro Spring. I don't understand how does CustomerEditorConfigurer knows where it should apply property conversion. Ex -

I have a Contact Class which has a date variable(jodatTime)
I created a ContactPropertyEditor whcih extends PropertyEditorSupport and I am using setAsText() to convert the String date.

I then go in application and define CustomerEditorConfigurer  where I am telling it to map jodaTime to ContactPropertyEditor. Now this does not have information which tells Spring that when a Contact class is created then do the conversion using ContactPropertyEditor.

So to test out my theory I created another class Contact2 with same property(Date) as Contact. When I run the conversion happens for Contact2 as well, which is little weird.

Here is the code sample
Contact.java

```
public class Contact {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private DateTime birthDate;
private URL personalSite;



public String toString() {
return "First name: " + getFirstName()
+ " - Last name: " + getLastName()
+ " - Birth date: " + getBirthDate()
+ " - Personal site: " + getPersonalSite();
}
// Getter/setter methods omitted
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public DateTime getBirthDate() {
    return birthDate;
}

public void setBirthDate(DateTime birthDate) {
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
}

public URL getPersonalSite() {
    return personalSite;
}

public void setPersonalSite(URL personalSite) {
    this.personalSite = personalSite;
}
}
```

ContactPropertyEditor.java
    import java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport;

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


public class ContactPropertEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

private DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter;

public ContactPropertEditor(String formatPattern){
    System.out.println("In the constructor");
    dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormat.forPattern(formatPattern);
}

public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    System.out.println("Setting the value of " + text);
    setValue(DateTime.parse(text, dateTimeFormatter));
}

}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.dinesh"></context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- This holds the property values and formats -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

<bean class="com.dinesh.PropertyEditor.ContactPropertEditor" id="contactPropertEditor">
    <constructor-arg><value>"yyyy-MM-dd"</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="org.joda.time.DateTime">
                <ref local="contactPropertEditor" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="clarence" class="com.dinesh.PropertyEditor.Contact"
    p:firstName="Clarence" p:lastName="Ho" p:birthDate="1970-12-31"
    p:personalSite="http://www.clarence.com" />



<bean id="contact2" class="com.dinesh.PropertyEditor.Customer2"
    p:firstName="Clarence" p:lastName="Ho" p:birthDate="1970-12-31"
    p:personalSite="http://www.clarence.com" />
```

Now as you can see all I am doing is telling org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer that my proprty conversion logic is contactPropertEditor class. I do not tell Spring that apply this on Contact.java class.

How is the magic happening.

In the Spring documentation it says something else which makes sense.

The Spring documentation has a Class called ExoticType() which has name property.
A editor calss called ExoticTypeEditor is used to chaage the name to Upper case and application context xml is clear

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
 <property name="customEditors">
   <map>
     <entry key="example.ExoticType" value="example.ExoticTypeEditor"/>
   </map>
 </property>
```

Here I can see that I am telling CustomEditorConfigurer that apply conversion on class ExoticType using ExoticTypeEditor but it is not the case in Pro Spring 3 book. I tried to do the same in Contact Example but got an error.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
    <property name="customEditors">
        <map>
            <entry key="com.dinesh.PropertyEditor.Contact">
                <ref local="contactPropertEditor" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Error : **Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type     [org.joda.time.DateTime] for property 'birthDate': no matching editors or conversion    strategy found**

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register a `PropertyEditor` in application context, you are providing  the converter from `String` to some type, in your case the `JodaTime` type. The bean holding the type, (`Contact`) don't matter. The application context will use your `ContactPropertyEditor` editor any time that need to set a property of type `JodaTime` as `String` on **any** bean.

So `ContactPropertyEdit` it's a bad name. It should be JodaTimePropertyEditor.

If you want a real `ContactPropertyEditor`, it should convert Strings to Contacts. For example:

```
<bean id="someBeanHoldingAContact" class="someBeanClass">
<property name="contact" value="Hendrix, Jimi, 1942-11-27, http://www.jimihendrix.com" />
</bean>
```

and the ContactPropertyEditor should use the string value to create the contact.

The *magic* is in `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImp` class. See the javadoc

Comment: -Thanks. I get it now. So this is like a global editor. Any bean that is using JodaTime will be affected. There is no way do it selectively. Say I only want to apply propertyEditor on a specific Bean only.

Comment: No, the container don't check the target class when looking for property editors. But you could implement the conversion in the bean itself or inject the object returned by other bean method deployed in the container.

Answer (score 0):

If people googled this title trying to find how to get the target class dynamically at conversion time, you can try using a ConditionalGenericConverter instead.

Relevant parts:

Check every conversion request:

```
    @Override
public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
    return null;//accept everything
}
```

Check when a conversion is requested if you handle this case or pass it to the spring default converter:

```
 @Override
public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
       if (sourceType.getType().equals(String.class) && MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(targetType.getType()))
        return true; 
return false;
}
```

Handle the conversion:

```
@Override
public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {    
output = targetType.getType().newInstance();
//do whatever is required here
return output;
}
```